# how can i integrate 2 squared function?

Tags: python, function, integrate

[image]

[image]

what i want to do is calculate i(rms)

and i have initial value and i(t) function

```
I0 = 1; T0 = 0.05; beta = 0.2 

import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate

I0 = 1; T0 = 0.05; beta = 0.2 

def i(x):
    return I0*(np.sin(np.pi*x/T0)-beta*np.sin(2*np.pi*x/TO))

integ = integrate.quad(i**2,0,T0)[0]

irms = np.sqrt(integ/T0)
print("i(rms) = ", irms)
```

but i got error like this

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-b60f32acb4dc> in <module>
      7     return I0*(np.sin(np.pi*x/T0)-beta*np.sin(2*np.pi*x/TO))
      8 
----> 9 integ = integrate.quad(i**2,0,T0)[0]
     10 
     11 irms = np.sqrt(integ/T0)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'function' and 'int'
```

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you are using `x**y` which is like using [pow](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_pow.asp).
the pow function takes 2 numbers while you are passing a function (`i`) as the first argument. Maybe you want to pass the result of the call to `i`?

BTW - using `i` as a name for a function is not the best practice.